# Creating XML File from PHP but get HTML one

Tags: php, mysql, xml

I'm using this code to create an XML file (not filed) from a PHP one. Here is the code:

```
<?php
include_once ('conf.php');
$conn =  mysql_connect($host, $user, $password);    
if (!$conn) {
    die('No hay conexion a la BBDD');
}
$bd = mysql_select_db($name, $conn);
if (!$bd) {
    die ('Error en la BBDD');
}
$query = "select * from usuarios where activo = 0 order by puntuacion desc limit 0, 10";
$res = mysql_query($query, $conn);
$salida = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes" ?>'."\n";
$salida .= '<score>'."\n";
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
    $salida.= '<posicion num="' . $i . '">'."\n";
    $salida .= '<id>'.$row['id'].'</id>'."\n";
    $salida .= '<puntuacion>'.$row['puntuacion'].'</puntuacion>'."\n";
    $salida .= '</posicion>'."\n";
    $i++;
}
$salida .= '</score>';
mysql_free_result($res);
mysql_close($conn);
echo $salida;
?>
```

When I call this file I obtain (using Chrome Inspector) the XML file embeded in a HTML file with its html, head and body tags. I want this php file to get readed by an ajax's get function.

Any ideas about what is wrong?

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: Where do you tell Chrome inspector that it is an XML file? You aren't setting a `Content-Type: application/xml` header anywhere. But if you simply inspect source code manually you'll see the raw output.

Answer (score 2):

Add a header specifying that you're outputting XML. `header('Content-Type: text/xml')` right before you echo.

Comment: Fixed!!! Thanks all of you.

Answer (score 2):

Read the PHP manual about [XML Manipulation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.xml.php).

You will find juicy tools there to fetch, manipulate and create XML documents.

Also, before making any output, add a line `header ("Content-type: text/xml");` to your script, to specify for the client entity, that you are going to send XML and it should be parsed as XML. [header — Send a raw HTTP header](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php)

Comment: That's it. It's very difficult to generate *valid* XML with raw echo statements.

Comment: @ÁlvaroG.Vicario: Actually it's equally difficult to generate *valid* HTML with raw ech statements, that's why you use DOMDocument for the HTML all the time, right? ;)